# Audience Compilation and My Site Performance

Tags: audience-targeting, 2007, wss-3.0, my-site, performance

Is audience compliation anyhow related to My Site Performance?

My guess. No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend on alot of things, such as general server architecture, amount of audiences etc.

If you suspect that audience compilation causes this, you can just set the compilation schedule to run saturday night or another time where your site has low traffic.

Comment: Can you be bit descriptive.

Comment: About the compilation schedule? Sure. Check out this configuration doc on TechNet:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262334.aspx

Comment: I want to compile the audience an hourly basis however there is no direct way to accomplish this through SSP (available options in SSP are day/weekly/monthly basis), do you have any suggestion for me on this ?

Comment: you might want to investigate if audiences at all is the reason for this performance issue at all (i dont find it an obvious candidate) before changing this.
Unless you expect hourly changes in your AD i see no reason why you would recompile your audiences at an hourly basis.

Comment: soon, we are going to launch the application globally which may require to compile the audience every hour (may be for first couple of days). do you have any suggestion for me on this ?

Comment: You can compile audiences using AudienceJob.RunAudienceJob http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.audience.audiencejob.runaudiencejob.aspx